# Presenting Data to Cross Platform Devices

Tags: architecture, cross-platform

I have an object that I serialize and pass to a web service, it has two enums. Should I look to remove these enums if I want developers of other platforms to create and consume this data? Or can other platforms handle serialized .net types?

My current platform is .net, I will be looking to expand the service to iOS and Android.

Comment: In cross-platform environments always apply a contract first approach, do not just serialize a proprietary (java, .net, etc) object. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not send an enum over a web service unless you have controll over server and client and they are on the same platform.

The ability to send an enum over a WCF web service was first available in .net 4.0. This will not work with .net 3.5.

Your best bet cross platform is to use REST based services.